# How should I update a MySQL table column with the average of other two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table with the following columns: `id (AI, PK), name, surname, group, grade1, grade2, average` and I must insert from a PHP script the average value of `'grade1'` and `'grade2'` in the `'average'` column.

I have used:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(`average`) SELECT AVG((`grade1` + `grade2`)/2.0) FROM table_name GROUP BY `id`
```

I have the grades inserted, but somehow when I run the SQL statement, *it creates new rows* only with the average values. I need to UPDATE the column 'average' in the existing rows, not create new ones.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `update`, not `insert`:

```
update table_name
    set average = (grade1 + grade2) / 2;
```

I should note that having such a calculated column is dangerous, because it can get out-of-synch.  Much safer are generated columns, which you can express as:

```
alter table table_name add column average decimal(10, 2)
    generated always as ( (grade1 + grade2) / 2);
```

This is calculated when the value is *queried* so it is always up-to-date.

Comment: It works this way, but if I insert new students with grades and names, I must drop the average column so I can update it again, and I need to perform several operations with the average column.

Comment: @Daniel . . . This addresses exactly that concern by suggesting a calculated column.  And you don't have to "drop" the column either to update new values or to main a calculated column, so I have no idea what "dropping" is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` instead of `INSERT INTO ...`

I would also consider to use a trigger instead of using PHP.